# How to change the toolbar's icon dynamically in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, icons

I am building a login part for a eclipse plugin project, but I am blocked by changing the icon of my toolbar after auto login. I use IElementUpdater to get the element when click the login button. But when it is auto login, I can not get the element, is there any way that I can change the icon like element.setIcon(). I start auto login by using IStartup extension point.
I tried ControlContribution, there's no exact example for me. So could some one help me to figure out this blocker? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can force the `updateElements` call using the command service:

```java
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService)window.getService(ICommandService.class);

commandService.refreshElements("command id", null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I can fix it with your advice.

Comment: The code in the second line just refresh the element, but how can I set the element,like element.setIcon(imageDescriptor). Thank you again. I tried many ways and still can not find a good solutions. Could you give me more information?